# Вывод пользователя из базы данных MySQL

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Все доброго времени суток! В общем дела такое: у меня в таблице есть поле `speed` (скорость машины). Теперь мне нужно написать код, который вытащит из базы соперника. Например у которого:

- скорость не больше 100 и не меньше 90
- скорость 90, 93, 94, 100, 97 если у меня 100
- если, например, у меня 260, то вытащить соперника не больше 260 и не меньше 250: например 253, 260, 258, и т.д.

Думаю, Вам понятно! Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: @ромыч, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @ромыч, Пожалуйста, исправьте грамматические ошибки и правильно расставьте запятые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допилил чутка:

```
$speed = $_POST['speed']; // получаем значение скорости
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users_speed WHERE speed BETWEEN '$speed' AND '$speed'-10 ")
```

Comment: с синтаксисом беда.

Comment: исправил...

Comment: нет, не исправил. :) Я вижу непонятно откуда взятый кусок кода который не будет работать никогда!

Сохраню на память

>$speed = $POST_('speed'); // получаем значение скорости
>$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users_speed WHERE speed >BETWEEN '$speed' AND '$speed'-10 ")

Comment: успокойся, будь корректнее!

Comment: мне отдельную таблицу создавать???

Comment: не надо, если у тебя всегда -10

Answer (score 0):

1. Сделай еще таблицу диапазона скоростей
2. Формируй динамически запрос, который будет выбирать соперника из заданных рамок

   ```
   select car from table where speed=>нижняя_граница and speed<=верхняя_граница
   ```

Comment: а не могли бы написать код если можно!?

Comment: запрос же написал =) пхп не знаю

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users_speed` WHERE `speed` BETWEEN 100 AND 90");

Comment: или $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users_speed` WHERE `speed`>'90' AND `speed`<'100'");